# CSS Hide Header on Home Page

Tags: html, css, header, hide

New theme and no hide\disable option for page.  I would like to hide the header ONLY on the home page: restoresell.com

Please advise of css code sample I can try or ?

SOURCE LINK: view-source:https://restoresell.com/

Thank You

Comment: Paste the code of your site over here. [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Google and DuckDuckGo have placed a security warning on this site stating that it's potentially unsafe. Be careful before visiting the site in this post by Gary Shif.

Comment: @wildernessfamily although I can appreciate your discovery ... You should know that as stated above...its a new domain with a new theme and the SSL has been updated yet.. hence "UN_SAFE" 
Via Cpanel: " AutoSSL Domain Validated
Expires on September 29, 2021. The certificate will renew via AutoSSL when the parent domain “restoresell.com” renews."

Comment: @GaryShif NO, that's not true. I've been a full-stack developer for almost three decades now. You can have a site that does not have an SSL installed, you can have your own SSL installed & the "Browser" will give an alert that this site is self-signed. You can even have an SSL installed that is misconfigured. You will receive a "Browser" warning. Google & Duck Duck Go has marked the site a "SECURITY WARNING" that there is potential "malware" on your site! That is completely different. To be safe, publish your code in your post. I used CubeOS to check & the security alert has been removed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have checked your code and if you simply want to hide your header on your homepage you can add this into your CSS and this will automatically hide your header

```
.header-top-home-three.home-four {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    visibility: hidden;
}


.vc_row {
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 108px;
}

.header.home-page-four {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 0;
    border: none;
    position:inherit;
    background: #fff;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.header .header-navigation.stricky-fixed {
    position: inherit;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #242424;
}
```

Comment: Thank You Shaurya.  This fix almost the entire issue... however, now im stuck with an empty field\area above the opening page area. my goal was for the home page to start at the beginning of the first page container\row.  See the white are a top of home page where the header was prior.

Thank You

Comment: You help is appreciated.  THANK YOU KINDLY

Comment: The above code still doesnt remove the header rather only the content.  If you notice it still has the white area where header was and the white area is still sticky as was the header.

}

Comment: Actually, I have published the wrong code accidently. Try this new one

Comment: 99% fixed... terrific progress.. BUT still the "sticky" header there when you scroll down.  if we can remove\disable that from the flow\UI we are 100% on target..

scroll down just a bit from top of page and you will see the white "bar" area floating as you scroll

Comment: Now you can check I have updated the code

Comment: Shaurya,
Same... Still got that nav white bar showing when you first start to scroll down page

Comment: I think it has to do with NAV not HEADER ... I think you solved the header issue but its the Nav that is that white field..I think :-)

Comment: check it now with the updated code I have changed it. I think this time it will work perfectly :)

Comment: YES! YESS! YES! ...  You did it! 
Thank you so much ... I so appreciate your kind effort.

Gary

Comment: You are not going to believe this... its doing same in responsive mode when viewed on mobile device.  Can we make that rule\script to include mobile devices? ALL DEVICES which land on the home page? 

Thank You Kindly

Comment: I think its this that need to be removed from code: "header-top-home-three home-four" the entire container probably .. not sure

Comment: Or better yet ... this ? : thm-container clearfix